# Manage Group broken on 4.7.5

Tags: upgrade, groups, 4.7, issues

after update to 4.7.5, the "manage Groups" page just says "No groups have been created for this site".

Although the groups are functioning otherwise.

This also happens on the sandbox/demo site.[image]

Answer (score 3):

Please follow https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18376 for the resolution of this issue.